# Removing terms with more than 2 variables

Tags: filtering, variable

Say I have the variable

```
x = a + a b + a b c + a b c d + ....
```

What is the easiest way to remove all terms with more than 2 variables? Up until now, I have used

```
x = a + a b + a b c + a b c d
coeffs = CoefficientRules[x, {a, b, c, d}];
selects = Select[coeffs, Total@(#[[1]]) <= 2 &];
x = FromCoefficientRules[selects, {a, b, c, d}]
```

Which works, but it requires me to manually enter each of the variable names. This becomes a tedious procedure when the number of variables is very high. Is there an easier way without specificing the variable names?

Comment: What if  instead of `a, b, c, ...` you use indexed variables, e.g., `a[1], a[2], a[3], ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = a + a b + a b c + a b c d;

Select[x, Length[#] < 3 &]

(* a + a b *)
```

or

```
DeleteCases[x, _?(Length[#] > 2 &)]

(* a + a b *)
```

or

```
Total@Cases[x, _?(Length[#] < 3 &)]

(* a + a b *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your manual selection of variables with an automated selection:

```
x = a + a b + a b c + a b c d
coeffs = CoefficientRules[x, Variables[x]];
selects = Select[coeffs, Total@(#[[1]]) <= 2 &];
x = FromCoefficientRules[selects, Variables[x]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Variables` to obtain them without manually entering them:

```
x /. Verbatim[Plus][terms___] :> Plus @@ Pick[{terms}, UnitStep[2 - Length@*Variables /@ {terms}], 1]
```

Comment: Your answer applied to `x = a + a b + a b c + a b c d` evaluates `0`?